# Is O(n) or O(1) more efficient for modifying arrays in-place?

Tags: javascript, arrays, big-o, in-place

For example,

```
function increaseByOne(nums) {

const increased = [];

for (let i = 0 ; i < nums.length ; i++) {
    increased.push(nums[i] + 1);
}

return increased;
```

or

```
function increaseByOneInPlace(nums) {

for (let i = 0 ; i < nums.length ; i++) {
    nums[i]++;
}

return nums;
```

example outputs:

```
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

console.log(increaseByOne(nums));
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

console.log(increaseByOneInPlace(nums));
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Which is more efficient? Why? I understand O(n) squared is worse because we have to run operations exponentially if running inside a nested loop, but I'm having trouble understanding the difference between O(n) or O(1)

(bonus: is there other ways we can have a function that's o(n) squared or is it just nested loops)

Comment: O(1) means it takes the same time regardless of array size. It's going to be faster than O(n) for sufficiently large n. O(n) means the size increases linearly with size so larger array=more time

Comment: See https://danielmiessler.com/study/big-o-notation/

Comment: *"O(n) squared"*: there is no O(n²) here.

Comment: Woops, sorry for the poorly worded question, I meant to say instead, "I understand O(n) squared(not shown) is less efficient than both examples shown O(n) and O(1)" I think Apokryfos had a good answer.

Comment: As others have pointed out. both do the same number of operations per (n). Your space requirements would change here though. If you want the Big O of space then one is O(n) (Since one is creating new memory with the number of elements n) and one is O(1) that's correct. But usually we care more about algorithm efficiency or time complexity, but sometimes we might look at space complexity as well if it is important.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your functions works for O(n) complexity

increaseByOne uses more memory O(2n) because increased array